# Universal Google Analytics not working

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on tracking [eCommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce), I am successful in implementing event tracking for my website, but I am not successful using eCommerce. gaTracker is my alias for ga.

```
gaTracker.send('ecommerce:addTransaction', { 'id': 'OrderId', 'affliation': 'abc',
'revenue': 'GrandTotal', 'shipping': 'ShippingTotal', 'tax': 'TaxTotal' }); 
gaTracker.send('ecommerce:addItem', { 'id': 'OrderId', 'name': productName, 'sku': sku,
'category': '', 'price': price, 'quantity': quantity}); 
gaTracker.send('ecommerce:send');
```

I already have `ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');` and I am using the universal analytics JavaScript snippet.

I waited 24 hours, I turned on the eCommerce setting in GA.

Can somebody help me with this.

`gaTracker.send();` this worked for me already with the event tracking.

Thanks

Comment: make sure that price and quantity are actually integers.

Answer (score 0):

after loading GA in your page

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

Follow this:

[image]